# Parsing data with REGEX (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, loops

I want to parse data in between brackets. Below is the code where you can see what I'm doing. I would also like to avoid using XML.

```
$query = '
    [page:1]
          <html>
                all the html
          </html>
    [/page:1]


    [page:2]
          <html>
                all the html
          </html>
    [/page:2]
';
```

I want to create a loop script that will use regex to find all instances of [page:x]; which in the example above is 2.  And then with a get function we can specify the page we want.

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {

      $page = $_GET['page'];
      $regex = '\\['page':(.*?)\\';

      echo preg_match($regex, $query);

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: my thought is that it isn't clear what your question is. Please clarify the question title and description.

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error when trying to run this?

Comment: url.php?page=1 would pull content from [page:1]mycontent[/page1] and the output would be "mycontent".  or for url.php?page=2 it would pull content in between [page:2] second page stuff[/page2] ouput would be "second page stuff".  It has to be dynamic though, because any database entry could have any amount of page brackets ([page:x])

Comment: Can't you store the pages in a saner manner in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should find all the matching blocks at once:

```
preg_match_all('/\[page:([0-9]+)\](.+?)\[\/page:$1\]/', $page, $matches)
```

I strongly doubt regex is the most suitable solution for what you're trying to accomplish though.